# DotCover Not giving coverage for refrenced DLL

Tags: c#, .net, code-coverage, dotcover

i donwloaded the `dotcover 1.1.1` for evaluation.
We use a automation framework to run regression test where application `'X'` refrences application `'Y'`s DLL .
I need code coverage of application `Y` when i run test through application `'X'`.
But all i m getting is code coverage for app `X`!

This is not the case with other code coverage tool.

Could you please suggest where i may be going wrong?

Comment: I could imagine wanting to enable/disable that, is it an option/attribute?

Comment: google search http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5277861

Comment: thanks kenny.. went through that link but i want to set that using console. That means in the xml config that is given as argument to dotCover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotCover doesn't support including referenced DLL's from command prompt for Code coverage yet( till 1.1.1).
Though Using DotCover GUI and unchecking "match with current project structure" option before starting Profiling for coverage allows coverage on referenced DLL's as well.
http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5277861?

This doesn't solve the problem as integration into automated testing framework cannot be achieved by using GUI.